# Sending SMS to Numbers with Five- or Six-Digit Short Codes Are Bounced

Tags: sms, system-error, sprint

The error message I receive is, "Error: this message was not successfully delivered." This happens whenever texting my bank, or other business services that use short codes like this (e.g., 50292, or 22000) for customer interaction. I can receive their messages but I cannot send back any replies to them. They always fail with the same stated error message. I happen to be using a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S5 running on stock firmware. For SMS messaging I've preferred to use Google Voice (it's linked up to my Sprint number and handles my voice-mail too), but the error still happens on the stock SMS messaging app.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the solution was to decouple my Sprint number from the Google Voice service. The instructions to stop using the Sprint number are at https://support.google.com/voice/answer/1207070?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en. It says,

> Stop using Google Voice on your Sprint phone
>
> I use my Sprint number
>
> Use a computer to remove the Sprint number from your account.
>
> ```
> On your computer, open Google Voice.
>
> At the top left, click Menu Menu and then Legacy Google Voice.
> Google Voice will look different, but you're in the right place.
>
> At the top right, click Settings Settings and then Settings. Click
> the "Phones" tab.
>
> You'll see your Sprint mobile number with the note "Enabled by
> Sprint." Next to your Sprint mobile number, click Disable.
>
> After you turn off Google Voice, you'll have to record a new
> voicemail greeting for your Sprint phone service.
> ```

Now I am able to text those five digit and six digit phone numbers and get a reply back using my stock messaging app without an error!